# PHP/SOAP - How to print multiple results

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to parse the result in PHP from a SOAP request.

Sometimes the response can be in a single object, but sometimes it can be multiple array results, and then my PHP breaks.

If it's only a single result (Object), then I have no problem to print it out:

```
<?php
echo $nuvarandetidigareagarefraga_output->return->foregaendeAgare->fv12->FV12_Agare_fr_o_m;
echo $nuvarandetidigareagarefraga_output->return->foregaendeAgare->fg01->FG01_Personnummer;
echo $nuvarandetidigareagarefraga_output->return->foregaendeAgare->fg01->FG01_Namn;
echo $nuvarandetidigareagarefraga_output->return->foregaendeAgare->fg02->FG02_Adress;
echo $nuvarandetidigareagarefraga_output->return->foregaendeAgare->fg02->FG02_Postnummer;
echo $nuvarandetidigareagarefraga_output->return->foregaendeAgare->fg02->FG02_Postort;
?>
```

But when it's multiple responses (Array), I have to use something like:

```
<?php
echo $nuvarandetidigareagarefraga_output->return->foregaendeAgare[0]->fg01->FG01_Namn;
?>
```

Is it possible to make loop of some kind instead to always show the results?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the response that breaks your code, and the stacktrace of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this simple solution:

```
foreach($nuvarandetidigareagarefraga_output->return->foregaendeAgare as $element){
    print $element->fg01->FG01_Namn;
}
```

?
If yes then please consult php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php section about loops.